# Python | request | dahua api || 401 when requesting the dahua cgi

Tags: python

I'm a beginner at python.
Recently, I have been trying to request the dahua dvr cgi for various usages.
However, I was stuck at the beginning. Every time I request the API it always return 401 with various config I had tried.

###### Then, here is the model and current config of my Testing DVR :

Model : DH/HCVR5104HS-V6/-AF-DVR-II-A/4-1
Software Version : V4.001.0000000.16
Hardware Version : V1.0
Web Version : V3.2.7.144755
SSL : False

Example code

```
from requests import get

res = get("http://192.168.0.50:1234/cgi-bin/global.cgi?action=getCurrentTime",auth=("user","pass"))
print(res.status_code)
##return 401
```

```
from requests import get

res = get("http://user:pass@192.168.0.50:1234/cgi-bin/global.cgi?action=getCurrentTime")
print(res.status_code)
##return 401
```

I have also tried adding cert argument with the ca cert which could downloaded from the admin page,
and it clearly not working.

I apologize for my ignorance.
Is there any possibility to return some config from dahua dvr/nvr with python?
Or how to use auth correctly in this case?
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTTP digest authentication, for example to get snapshot on Dahua Camera:

```
import requests
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

url = "http://user:pass@IP:PORT/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=1"

r = requests.get(url, stream=True, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('login', 'password')) 

if r.status_code == 200:
                #print ('entrou')
                with open('snapshot.jpeg', 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(r.content)
```